# Test step should stop when testStep Script assertion fails

Tags: groovy, soapui

i have to run the testStep multiple time with different data loading from external file(using file object looping to run the testSteps for each record) and validate the data from response for each value.
i'm able to do that and its executing and works fine. but when ever assert fails execution is not stoping and it will continue and shows testStep is passed. 
i can see the failed in "script log" windows whenever it fails because i'm using log.info with run.status

and i check checkbox for "abort if test if any error occurs" and "failed tes cases if testStep fails" on test case options.

still it continue executing the test cases

Important Note: above scenario happens when assert fails in middle of the records, if it is fails for last record then its stopping the execution.

Code which i used

This Groovy script code: file iterates the testStep as per the no of rows in file

```
// Get tha path to an input file from a custom property
def inputFilePath = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "inputFile" )
// Get the test case we want to Run
def tc=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["DetectRules"].testSteps["Rules_DENF_224"]

// Iterate through the input file

File file = new File(inputFilePath.toString()).eachLine{

// Set Test Suite custom properties
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "InValue", it.split(",")[0] )
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "OutValue", it.split(",")[1] )
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "outDesc", it.split(",")[2] )

def runner = tc.run(testRunner,context)

//Get the Json response from execution

def FraudReq = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["DetectRules"].testSteps["Rules_DENF_224"].testRequest.response.responseContent

// Log info to a output

log.info "Execution of test case with Input value: ${it.split(",")[0]} and expected returned value: ${it.split(",")[1]} and Expected Description is: ${it.split(",")[2]} ${runner.status}"

// Sleep for a second since were using public service
sleep 500
}


this is testStep --> Script Assertion: section

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response= messageExchange.response.responseContent
 def jsonsl= new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

 def expected=context.getTestCase().getPropertyValue(“rule number”)
assert  expected==jsonsl.results[4].id
```

if above assert fails then testStep should stop ,but testStep failing but execution is not stopped.

any help appreciated

Comment: You need to supply examples on what you are currently doing. Is the test execution done inside a Groovy Script teststep? Have you done some try-catch construction, and just throws away the error? Something else? If you put up a generic question, we will at best be able to come up with something along the lines of "have you considered", which quickly turn into a guessing game.

Comment: It’d be useful to see your assertion/validation code.

Comment: add code example here .